# Does unused database hurt MySQL server performance in any way?

Tags: mysql, performance

If there are some unused databases on MySQL server is it better to remove those from server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they're unused then by all means remove them.

However, leaving them around *shouldn't* hurt day-to-day performance as they aren't referenced by any application.

They will have an impact on the server performance in areas such as backups etc. as they are more data that has to be checked and copied etc.

Comment: I also suppose it shouldn't, but needed more of a "sure" answer.

Comment: When ChrisF says "shouldn't", he says that because it's just possible there might be a difference (the internal tables will be a bit bigger, there might be an issue with disk fragmentation, that sort of thing), but if your disk is large enough don't worry about it, because any difference is extremely unlikely to be visible to the naked eye.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it CAN hurt performance because it will mean more RAM is being used and if you are low on RAM this can cause issues.

For example, lets say you have **website_new** and unused **website_old** databases. If you had innodb pool set to 3GB then you would need to increase that if the **website_old** is left sitting there.

Keeping old DBs around will force you to skew your my.cnf config to maintain performance.

hope this helps